# Minimum number of edges must be removed from a hypercube cube to receive no cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph whose vertex set is the set of length $n$ 0-1 sequences. Two such sequences can be connected by an edge, iff they differ in exactly one position. How many edges need to be deleted at least so $G$ becomes cycle-free? I started with the first two cases but couldn't see any patterns from there.

Comment: You know the number of edges in a tree on $n$ vertices?

Comment: Do you know how many vertices your graph has? Do you know how many edges your graph has? Do you know the maximum number of edges a cycle-free graph on $m$ vertices can have? Combine these three things, and you should have your answer.

Comment: I know the first two, but third one I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have deleted the minimal number of edges -- in some order -- to make your graph acyclic.

If the graph is now *not connected*, that means you have deleted *too many* edges. Namely, consider the *first* edge you deleted that made the graph disconnected. It must go between two vertices in different connected components of the eventual graphs, and therefore if you put it back in, it can't be part of any cycle. So you didn't need to remove it after all.

Thus, the graph you end up with is *acyclic* and *connected*. An acyclic connected (undirected) graph is a *tree*, and hopefully you know that a tree with $V$ vertices always has $V-1$ edges.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I have that the graph has $2^n $ vertices, and $n2^{n-1} $ edges. So by what you say, a tree would have $2^{n}-1$ edges. Thus i must remove $n2^{n-1}-(2^n-1) $ edges.

Comment: @user503189: Yes.